# Non-immediate updating model?

Tags: angularjs

AngularJS's data-binding is neat, but I don't want my view to be immediately updated until the user presses a "save" button. How can I delay  updating the view while still keeping the binding between my text inputs and `{{placeholders}}`?

Comment: Hrm..the example they give here seems to be pretty close to what I want: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Comment: Just make a copy of the form and don't attach that to scope before you finish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bind the temporary object just for the form and let "save" button handler to copy the form object into your main data model.

here is the example: http://plnkr.co/edit/4vuduD

in html:

```
<form ng-submit="update()">
  <label>name: <input ng-model="formobj.name"/></label>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
saved name : {{ obj.name }}
```

in js:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.formobj = {name: ""};
  $scope.obj = {name: ""};
  $scope.update = function() {
    $scope.obj = angular.copy($scope.formobj);
  };
});
```

Comment: I guess since this is an edit form all I have to do is copy the `obj` into the `formobj` when they click "Edit", and then as you demonstrated, copy it back when they're done. I like this; looks about as simple as can be. Thanks!